# No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package + RetinaFace

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed RetinaFace and TensorFlow for my project and when I run, this error appear. for RetinaFace I should use TensorFlow with 2.1.0 version and for this I cant upgrade or downgrade it.
I reinstall and install TensorFlow for several time but it doesn't fix my issue.

> python: 3.6.0
> TensorFlow: 2.1.0
> RetinaFace: 0.0.6
> on windows

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.tools'; 'tensorflow.python' is not a package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this version of TensorFlow is available from python3.7 up

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).